# access select query between 2 date fields as criteria

Tags: ms-access-2010

Trying to figure out how to select records in Access where there are 3 fields: Manuf_Date, Date_Opened  and Record ID. I want to find records where  Date_Opened  is 2 years greater than Manuf_Month_Year.

I entered this function as criteria in access under the Manuf_Month_Year field

```
<=DateAdd("yyyy",-2,[(dbo_TW_Parent_Child_All_Records.Date_Opened])

<=DateAdd("yyyy",-2,[(dbo_TW_Parent_Child_All_Records.Date_Opened])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with some syntax clean-up:

```
<=DateAdd("yyyy",-2,[dbo_TW_Parent_Child_All_Records].[Date_Opened])
```